# Confused regarding outbound data transffer in azure free tier

Tags: azure, outbound

I want to know that it is mentioned on the azure free tier page that:
15 GB of bandwidth for outbound data transfer with free unlimited inbound transfer
And at one place it is mentioned that:
5 GB of bandwidth for outbound data transfer with free unlimited inbound transfer

So, I'm completely confused here.
I want to know that if I create a B1S virtual machine and I don't have any credits in my account during free tier, how much outbound data will I get?
Is 15 GB and 5 GB applies to virtual machines also or to specific services only?
I'm unable to identify/figure out that for a B1S VM during my free tier, how much outbound data transfer I'll be able to do.
Also, for a B1S virtual machine, which kind of disk I should select so that I do not get charged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/):
[image]

This basically means:

- in the first 12 months of using your Free tier account, you get 15 GB outbound traffic included. Although I'm not sure if this means "every month of the first 12 months you get 15 GB or if you get 15 GB to use over the course of 12 months - and they could already be fully used after 3 weeks...
- In any Azure account, the [first 5 GB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/) of outbound data transfer is always included per month.

**None of this relates at all to any VM you provision etc**. The outbound data quota counts towards all your services in Azure together. As long as you VMs don't send data out over the internet or you download data from those VMs etc., they will not really incur much outbound traffic.

Comment: Hmm, so it means that if I host websites in my VMs then I can have 15 gb of outbound only including all the azure services. pretty sad if our apps/website gets heavy traffic sometime unknowingly. :(

Comment: I don't know if it is sad if your website gets popular... plus, have you actually looked at the bandwidth costs? they shouldn't kill you... https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/